# How to change disable text color in JXHyperlink in swing?

Tags: java, swing

I need to change default disable text color in JXHyperlink. Is there any way to do this? JXHyperlink extends JButton.

I tried with isEnable validation and set foreground color accordingly, but foreground color only affected for isEnable true scenario.

Comment: [`JXHyperlink#setClickedColor`](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXHyperlink.html#setClickedColor(java.awt.Color))?

Comment: change the background color

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jHyperLink.setEnabled(false);
jHyperLink.setText("<html><font color = red>"+jHyperLink.getText()+"</font></html>");
```